# Lower the brightness of all RGB pixels by 20% in Python?

Tags: python, image

I have been trying to teach myself more advanced methods in Python but can't seem to find anything similar to this problem to base my code off of.

First question: Is this only way to display an image in the terminal to install Pillow? I would prefer not to, as I'm trying to then teach what I learn to a very beginner student. My image.show() function doesn't do anything.

Second question: What is the best way to go about lowering the brightness of all RGB pixels in an image by 20%? What I have below doesn't do anything to the alter the brightness, but it also can compile completely. I would prefer the most simple way to go about this as far as importing minimal libraries.

Third Question: How do I made a new picture instead of changing the original? (IE- lower brightness 20%, "image-decreasedBrightness.jpg" is created from "image.jpg")

here is my code - sorry it isn't formatted correctly. Every time i tried to indent it would tab down to the tags bar.

```
import Image
import ImageEnhance

fileToBeOpened = raw_input("What is the file name? Include file type.")
image = Image.open(fileToBeOpened)

def decreaseBrightness(image):
    image.show()
    image = image.convert('L')
    brightness = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image) 
    image = brightness.enhance(20) 
    image.show() 
    return image

decreaseBrightness(image)
```

Comment: Well the basic question is: do you want to use some quality-library and write a few lines which are easy to understand or do you want to write it from scratch and have to implement the most obscure and ugly functions by yourself (parsing on bytelevel; maybe color-transformations, ...). I always prefer the former (if the libraries are really good and if i can use them regarding license / install...). Pillow is a candidate; scikit-image is even better!

Answer (score 0):

To save the image as a file, there's an example on the documentation:

```
from PIL import ImageFile

fp = open("lena.pgm", "rb")

p = ImageFile.Parser()

while 1:
    s = fp.read(1024)
    if not s:
        break
    p.feed(s)

im = p.close()

im.save("copy.jpg")
```

The key function is `im.save`.

For a more in-depth solution, get a nice beverage, find a comfortable place to sit and enjoy your read:
[Pillow 3.4.x Documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/).

Comment: Should be the *easiest* way. Really try reading the documentation for `Pillow.ImageFile`.

Comment: @MeganByers Python doesn't have any built-in image support. You'll have to import *something*.